# How to remove .has-error input styling for one element?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I style this last input using id
`#event_fb_website {...}` so it's styled like regular input without errors?

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <div class="field_with_errors"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="event_website">Website URL</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="field_with_errors"><input placeholder="http://..." class="form-control" type="url" value="" name="event[website]" id="event_website"></div>
        <span class="help-block">
          Website can't be blank
        </span>
      <input placeholder="http://..." class="form-control" type="url" value="" name="event[website]" id="event_fb_website">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Without errors? 
What kind of errors are you having, darly?

Comment: Without errors = without this red border and red glow effect.

Comment: It's kind of obviously, don't you think? remove class `has-error` inside this `div` tag;  `<div class="form-group has-error">`

Comment: But it clears styling from both inputs, and I want to clear it from last one only.

Comment: You can add div with `class= form-group` as many as you think its necessary. Close the first tag and add again for specific input.

Comment: I need to do this by styling this single element.

Comment: But bootstrap gives you the option removing this. (¬_¬)"

Answer (score 0):

Just style your input like it was in the default state

```
#event_fb_website {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#event_fb_website:focus {
    border-color: rgba(82,168,236,.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
 }
```

Comment: Yep, but when you click on it, there is no glow effect.

Comment: It's close now, just add this blue glow from regular state and it's an answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why someone minus this question, anyway answer is:

```
#event_logo_url {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#event_logo_url:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
}
```

and probably this:

```
#event_logo_url::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
  opacity: 1;
}
#event_logo_url:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
#event_logo_url::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
```